# AndroidDriver giving ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, appium

I am still trying to get the example in this tutorial to work:

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/first-appium-test-script/

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException in the line:

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(caps);
```

I have added java-client-6.0.0-BETA2.jar to my Build Path.

What am I missing?

This is not in any way connected to the question: How to resolve 'the import io cannot be resolved' - that part has been resolved.

**Update 03/01/2018**

I have converted my project to a Maven project.
Then I added the following to the pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0-BETA2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I ran Maven Build with Verify Clean.

The result was still the same:

ClassNotFoundException

**Update 04/01/2018**

Finally got this working.
I got a response from Appium support - “Selenium requires guava library to be in classpath.”
First I added the android version - but that gave a different error.
When I added the regular version - it all worked:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>23.6-jre</version>
  <!-- or, for Android: -->
  <version>23.6-android</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve 'the import io cannot be resolved'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062523/how-to-resolve-the-import-io-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: No @Progman - it is not the same question. That one has been resolved.

Comment: How is this in any way connected to that last question?

Comment: @SteveStaple if your project has maven enabled, i would suggest trying to import Appium using the dependency method in your pom.xml

Comment: @mvoase - sorry - I know nothing about maven. Project is not maven enable as far as I am aware, & I have never used a pom file.

Comment: @SteveStaple If you're using IntelliJ.. right click on your project folder and hit Add Framework Support > Tick the Maven box and Hit OK. Maven is a Package Manger.. it generates and XML files called pom.xml - You can then link in dependencies which is like importing a JAR library. - I will add a full tutorial as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to add maven framework support to your project. 
If using IntelliJ do the following:

- Right Click your folder structure and hit Add Framework Support
- Then tick the Maven box and click OK to add this as  a Maven Project.
- You should then have a pom.xml generated within your folder structure open this.
- Within this pom.xml you need to add the following code: 
  https://gist.github.com/michaelvoase/54f3bbf47b888bb004330a1d1b108068

This will then import the Appium library into your project.

Comment: Thanks @mvoase - I tried all that - and added java-client:6.0.0-BETA2 to the Depencies in the pom.xml file. Also ran Maven build - verify clean. Still made no difference. Still getting ClassNotFoundException at the same line.